# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) python using txt

Tags: python, valueerror

i'm extracting the data from the file. when i try to print some especifics values, appears this

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-3ebd5a973be1> in <module>()
      5 fig.suptitle('file.txt')
      6 
----> 7 fs, data = np.loadtxt('file.txt', delimiter = ' ', unpack = True)
      8 
      9 tamdata = data.size

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

any ide how i can fix this?

```
import numpy as np

fs, data = np.loadtxt('file.txt', delimiter = ' ', unpack = True) #the error seems to be in this line

tamdata = data.size
duration = tamdata/fs
dt = duration/tamdata
t = np.arange(0,duration,dt)

print('Record frecuency fs = %.1f datos/s' % fs)
print('Number of data = %.f' % tamdata)
print('Duration = %f s'  % duration)
print('Temporary Sample = %f s' % dt)
```

Comment: What did you want to get as `fs` when you called `np.loadtxt`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What do/don't you understand from that error message? Also, is there a particular reason you're using the old % formatting?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to unpack it such that `fs` is the first column and `data` contains the remaining columns. If that's the case, then here's what you want:

```
fs, *data = np.loadtxt('file.txt', delimiter = ' ', unpack = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), when using `unpack=True` parameter, arrays are returned for each field. which means you will have to either use as many variables as there are fields in your file, or, just use one variable which might take all the fields returned by the function.

It seems there are more than 2 fields (fs and data)